# Python : How to translate?

Tags: python

the program is when user input"8#15#23###23#1#19###9#20"

output should be "HOW WAS IT"

However,it could not work to show space(###).

enter code here

```
ABSTRACT ={"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4","E":"5","F":"6","G":"7","H":"8","I":"9", "J":"10","K":"11","L":"12","M":"13","N":"14","O":"15","P":"16","Q":"17","R":"18","S":"19","T":"20","U":"21","V":"22","W":"23", "X":"24","Y":"25","Z":"26",
"   ":"###","":"#" }
ABSTRACT_SHIFTED = {value:key for key,value in ABSTRACT.items()}

def from_abstract(s):
    result = ''
    for word in s.split('*'):
        result = result +ABSTRACT_SHIFTED.get(word)

    return result
```

Comment: `s.split('*')`? But there is no `*` in your input.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

InputString = "8#15#23###23#1#19###9#20"

InputString = InputString.replace("###", "##")
InputString = InputString.split("#")

DecodedMessage = ""
for NumericRepresentation in InputString:
    if NumericRepresentation == "":
        NumericRepresentation = " "
        DecodedMessage += NumericRepresentation
        continue
    else:
        DecodedMessage += chr(int(NumericRepresentation) + 64)

print(DecodedMessage)
```

Prints:

```
HOW WAS IT
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a regex

```
import re

replacer ={"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4","E":"5","F":"6","G":"7","H":"8","I":"9", "J":"10","K":"11","L":"12","M":"13","N":"14","O":"15","P":"16","Q":"17","R":"18","S":"19","T":"20","U":"21","V":"22","W":"23", "X":"24","Y":"25","Z":"26",
"   ":"###","":"#" }
reversed = {value:key for key,value in replacer.items()}

# Reversed because regex is greedy and it will match 1 before 15
target = '8#15#23###23#1#19###9#20'
pattern = '|'.join(map(lambda x: x + '+', list(reversed.keys())[::-1]))
repl = lambda x: reversed[x.group(0)]

print(re.sub(pattern, string=target, repl=repl))
```

And prints:

```
HOW   WAS   IT
```

Answer (score 0):

With a couple minimal changes to your code it works.
1) split on '#', not '*'
2) retrieve ' ' by default if a match isn't found
3) use '##' instead of '###'

```
def from_abstract(s):
    result = ''
    for word in s.replace('###','##').split('#'):
        result = result +ABSTRACT_SHIFTED.get(word," ")
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap the key-value pairs of ABSTRACT and use simple `split` + `join` on input

```
ip = "8#15#23###23#1#19###9#20"
ABSTRACT = dict((v,k) for k,v in ABSTRACT.items())
''.join(ABSTRACT.get(i,' ') for i in ip.split('#')).replace('  ', ' ')
#'HOW WAS IT'
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest challenge here is that "#" is used as a token separator and as the space character, you have to know the context to tell which you've got at any given time, and that makes it difficult to simply split the string. So write a simple parser. This one will accept anything as the first character in a token and then grab everything until it sees the next "#".

```
ABSTRACT ={"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4","E":"5","F":"6","G":"7","H":"8","I":"9", "J":"10","K":"11","L":"12","M":"13","N":"14","O":"15","P":"16","Q":"17","R":"18","S":"19","T":"20","U":"21","V":"22","W":"23", "X":"24","Y":"25","Z":"26",
"   ":"###","":"#" }
ABSTRACT_SHIFTED = {value:key for key,value in ABSTRACT.items()}

user_input = "8#15#23###23#1#19###9#20"

def from_abstract(s):
    result = []
    while s:
        print 'try', s
        # tokens are terminated with #
        idx = s.find("#")
        # ...except at end of line
        if idx == -1:
            idx = len(s) - 1
        token = s[:idx]
        s = s[idx+1:]
    result.append(ABSTRACT_SHIFTED.get(token, ' '))
    return ''.join(result)

print from_abstract(user_input)
```